# Strip special characters from text file but keep new lines (Python)

Tags: python, special-characters

I have a text file that looks like the following:

Don't

Can't

Won't

Shouldn't

My aim is to remove all special characters from the text file, whilst preserving the new line for each word. Output should look like:

Dont

Cant

Wont

Shouldnt

I'm currently using the following code:

```
import re

class TextCleaner:
    uncleanText = open("words.txt").read()
    cleanText = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', uncleanText)
    open('words.txt', 'w').write(cleanText)
```

However, this outputs the following:
DontCantWontShouldnt

Can I achieve my primary aim whilst preserving the new lines using regex?

Comment: why not reading line by line? or just use `re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9\n]+', '', uncleanText)`

Comment: You're throwing away `\n` as well. That's the newline character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `\n` to preserve new lines or `\s` to preserve any white spaces. For `\s` it's this code:

```
import re

class TextCleaner:
    uncleanText = open("words.txt").read()
    cleanText = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9\s]+', '', uncleanText)
    open('words.txt', 'w').write(cleanText)
```